# Why concurrent http requests take as same as time compare to sequential execution?

Tags: python, python-3.x, concurrency

I learning about concurrent execution in python3.
I have no idea why following http request functions take as same as time despite one use concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExection other one does not.

```
import urllib.request as ur
import concurrent.futures

def concurrent_exe(): # concurrent exection function that use ThreadPoolExecutor. 
    thread_pool_exe = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor()
    for v in range(10000):
        future = thread_pool_exe.submit(access_example)
        print(v, future.result())

def access_example():
    return ur.urlopen("http://example.com").read().decode("utf-8")[10:15]

def seq_exe(): # sequential exectute function
    for v in range(10000):
        print(v, access_example())
```

I do not know why these functions take almost same time.

My Environment is:

- Python 3.6
- Ubuntu 18.10 on Virtual Box (Host OS: Windows10 1803)

Comment: `future.result()`, it is a blocking method. Or how could you print it?

Comment: you are still sequentially executing it is what sraw is getting at ...

Comment: How should I change to do concurrent execution in this code?

Comment: Should I wait until complete or stopped then get these results?

Answer (score 1):

I know what should I change in my code.
future.result is blocking method. so it should wait until finish first future.

```
def concurrent_exe():
    futures_list = []
    thread_pool_exe = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor()
    for v in range(10000):
        future = thread_pool_exe.submit(access_example, v)
        futures_list.append(future)
    for v in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures_list):
        print(v.result())
```